# Alpha Centauri (GOG version) is using up nearly 100% cpu

Tags: performance, alpha-centauri

SMAC is overheating my Win7 64-bit, Core Duo 2.0Ghz, 4GB RAM machine and when I check the Task Manager after playing a few minutes (nothing major happens in the game, I just build my base and move the scout around), I see the following: [image]

How should I stop this from happening? Is there a patch that counter-acts this? Would a CPU throttler work? Or something else?

I'm using the GOG version which is already supposed to be patched to the highest official version.

Comment: I've been advised this may have something to do with running SMAC on a 64-bit machine, but I haven't verified this myself yet.

Comment: Wow that game is as old as dirt. How odd. Spectacular game however. Good choice.

Comment: Yeah I did play it when it was first released. Came back for the nostalgia.

Comment: Considering that the GOG version doesn't (as of last time I checked) include Alien Crossfire, I don't see how it could be the most recent version.

Comment: It doesn't include AX but from what I've read the problem exists also on AX, even when patched.

Comment: Suggesting tag: alpha-centauri; synonyms: smac; related: smax

Comment: I had the same overheating issue with an old Windows XP 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I keep play SMAX till now, and it works fine on my Win7/x64.

1. Make a clean installation SMAX (or backup an existing copy);
2. Install SMAX patch, searchable `smacp4e`, last time seen [here](https://www.moddb.com/downloads/alpha-centauri-v40-english-patch);
3. Install Windows Fix, searchable `smacxp103fus` or *SMAC Win2000 XP Compatibility Update v1.03f*; last time seen [here](https://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/smac_win2000_xp_compatibility_update_v1-03f-zip.23387/).

As far as I know, all patches are available for SMAC and SMAX.

Then try the following settings in config:

```
[Alpha Centauri]
DirectDraw=0 ;; important
Video Mode=2560 ;; your screen resolution
ds3d=1
eax=1
FastUnitAnim=0
SmoothUnitAnim=0

[PREFERENCES]
ForceOldVoxelAlgorithm=1 ;; important
```

The patches above have quite a few of bugs fixed, including operation on fast or non-Intel CPU's, crashes on air-to-air combat (when fighter defend the city against bombers), division by zero when automated units in polar areas, and many others.

It even works like a charm on WQXGA (2560×1600) screen with no crashes on scrolling.

And it does not require any compatibility settings in Windows.

Comment: I eventually gave up and put WXP on a different machine, it works fine now, no high CPU usage. I think there are some weird processor calls being made that worked with WXP but don't work on W7. Anyway it's sorted now. Thanks. I will check this out and if it does behave okay on W7 then I'll accept it.

Comment: Where do you get these patches

Comment: @Mawg, online resources for old games get old and die out gradually, too, but googling for the patches' names ([with quotes for exact search](https://www.google.com/search?q="smacxp103fus")) usually gives me some results with download links.

Comment: I have been trying that. I got the first patch, but not the second  :-(

Comment: @Mawg, [Here it is](https://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/smac_win2000_xp_compatibility_update_v1-03f-zip.23387/). I've found it on my  old backup and revealed is full name `SMAC_Win2000_XP_Compatibility_Update_v1.03f.exe` within, which is searchable. I believe I got if from CivFanatics, too.

Comment: Thanks a million. Alsas, that did not help me, but hopefully it will help others. I bought my copy from Good Old Games, so it should auto-update :-(

Comment: @Mawg, sorry to learn that. Anyway, there are [lots](https://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/categories/alpha-centauri-downloads.111/) of patches and custom builds at CivFanatics, and I sincerely hope that you can try them to load your save file and see if they crash on it. Best luck.

Answer (score 3):

The game runs fine in 32-bit Windows XP (with the usual SMAC patches) on the same machine. It's still hard to prove, but I think it has a lot to do with being 32-bit.

My guess is that some CPU calls are being made that W7 64-bit can't handle properly. I don't know how to prove this, but I've seen it mentioned in several forum threads by now, and starting to see some correlation.

I'll update this when I've checked out a few more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Open Alpha Centauri.Ini file and under [Alpha Centauri] add this:
DirectDraw=0

Comment: Why does this fix it?