# Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri is crashing in the late game. Is it a resources problem?

Tags: technical-issues, alpha-centauri

I have been playing Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri since it came out, 20 years ago. I finally got around to playing on the hardest level. I am in the late game, just about the Gravship; it looks like I have a chance to win.

However, the game is now crashing. I would suspect a resource problem, except I have been playing exclusively on huge map of planet since the start, when my PC probably had only a few MB of RAM. My current laptop has 32 GB of RAM, which ought to be enough.

The only time I previously saw this was 5 years ago, when I made a custom sized map which was larger than the huge map. I now stick to huge, and have never once had a problem with the huge map until now.

I booted into safe mode, but terranx.exe won't run. I have tried a fresh boot, then kill a few processes, but with 32GB of RAM for a 1999 game, there shouldn't be a resource problem - unless it is a 32 bit thing.

Any ideas on how I can finish this game?

Comment: Do you know how much RAM the game is using when you load your map?  For a game made in 1999, it's highly likely to be that 32-bit thing.  See if you get near the 2GB limit for 32-bit applications.  It could also be a number of other issues, bad asset, etc.  That game for me was always somewhat unstable, but I was playing the Mac port.

Comment: Strange! I loaded the auto-save from one year previously, and task manager shows the game using only 33.1mB

Comment: Total memory usage 23%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possible causes:

1. Your system may not have all necessary patches, listed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/75567/25369) — namely, `smacp4e` and `smacxp103fus`;
2. There are some old builds that cause crashes when an *Air interceptor*-capable unit is set to *Sentry* on a friendly base (<kbd>Shift+L</kbd>), that base get attacked by an enemy's bomber, and your unit *automatically* stands up for protection. The symptom is that the crash occurs during the AI move, and you don't really see at what moment it crashes ([link](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/smac-smacx-carbon.44714/#post-785278), [link](http://www.codehappy.net/apolyton/threads/45144-1.htm)).

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000 for the patches If, for some reason they don't help I guess I will buy it (again) from Steam & hope that they have an updated version

Comment: It can be bought form Good Old Games. I found the first patch, but not smacxp103fus :-(

Comment: But GOG has a "keep game up to date" option, so no patching should be necessary